# Altura de div para que sea dinámico

Tags: html, css

Saludos a todos en la comunidad les comento un poco mi problema,

Quiero hacer que un div tenga su Height de manera dinamica...dependiendo del tamaño del formulario, este sea dinámico.

Este es el div, si se dan cuenta, tengo un Iframe dentro de el

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div id="centro" class="centro">
            <iframe id="iframeCentro"
                name="centro"
                width="100%" height="100%"
                scrolling="No" frameborder="0"
                class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fijense que dentro del DIV que tiene como ID "centro" esta la clase "centro" aqui les dejo lo que tengo como CSS en la clase "centro"

```
.centro
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: solid;
}
```

Pero al final se ve es asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si yo quiero que el formulario se vea, tendria que poner el Height en pixeles, pero esa no es la idea.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ven, la lista sale cortada...honestamente les digo el frontend no es mi fuerte...espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Todos los elementos `div` tienen tamaño dinámico sin embargo los `iframe` no y es porque no conocen el tamaño de su contenido hasta después de estar cargados por lo que debes reasignar el tamaño del `iframe` después de que este esté cargado, un ejemplo

```
<div style="border: 2px solid;">
<iframe id="frame" src="https://www.w3schools.com/" width="100%" onload="reSizeFrame()" style="display: block"></iframe>
</div>
<script>
    function reSizeFrame() {
      var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
      iframe.height = "";
      iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
    }    
</script>
```

Comment: Hola como estas? gracias por responder...lo he probado tal cual lo has puesto pero no me ha funcionado. Dice ReferenceError: reSizeFrame is not defined

Comment: Define la función antes del div y vuelve a probar. Un saludo.

Comment: le di id "frame" al `iframe` y así es como lo llamo después

Comment: Gracias...lo he mejorado...ya me ha funcionado

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas que el `height` sea automático como comentas por lo que debe ser `auto`. Puedes mantener el `overflow:hidden` pero dándoselo solo al eje de las x de este modo:

```
.centro {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    border: solid;
}
```

de este modo el contenedor se adaptará verticalmente al contenido que se genere dentro del mismo.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div id="centro" class="centro">
            <iframe id="iframeCentro"
                name="centro"
                width="100%" height="100%"
                scrolling="No" frameborder="0"
                class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Por si en el futuro alguien necesita una solucion mejorada he conseguido esta y me ha funcionado a la perfeccion.

Usando Jquery:

```
 $nombreIframe.on("load",function ()
{
    this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 100 + 'px';
});
```

Gracias a todos por sus respuestas y su ayuda.